# Allow guest read/write access to Netatalk AFP share

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, afp, netatalk

I am running Netatalk 3.14dev on Ubuntu 14.04. This box is being used as a webserver and we already have a Samba share pointed at the /var/www folder to allow our developers to work on sites hosted on the server.

The Samba share is configured to allow full guest read/write access, and files created / edited via the share are forced to be written as "www-data" so that Apache can use them.

How do we mirror this set up using Netatalk to allow Macs to connect via AFP? There are some permissions / locking issues with Samba and I'm trying AFP as a solution. I can configure the share using Netatalk but cannot allow guest write access - it is currently read only.

I have this in /usr/local/etc/afp.conf:

```
[Global]
; Global server settings
log file = /var/log/netatalk.log
uam list = uams_guest.so

[PHP Sites]
path = /var/www
file perm = 0664
directory perm = 0775
guest account = www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

`guest account` should be defined inside `[Global]` section. 
After fixing that, it should work.